# Using Linq2Sql relationships for linq only

Tags: linq-to-sql, one-to-many

I have two tables in Linq2Sql are a one-to-many relationship. Each have a reference to each other, either by a collection, or a single instance value.

I want to ensure my end users only use the collections for linq queries only. I don't want them to be able to add items to the collection and "SubmitChanges".

How do I register the collection with Linq2Sql as a collection but also tell it to never update (relationships only, not properties/fields) the database with the items in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can disable changetracking on your datacontext.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx

f ObjectTrackingEnabled is false, DeferredLoadingEnabled is ignored and treated as false. In this case, the DataContext is read-only.

Comment: I want to be able to save/update, but just setup some "no cascade"-like option for the collections.

Comment: ok, you might want to edit your question since it states: "but also tell it to never update"

Comment: Done. Sorry about that. I meant "never update the relationships in the collection".

Comment: I think what you want is that far away from how Linq2sq is intended that you really do not want to do this...